# Utilising for loop and numpy.tile to create an array of alternating values i.e. (1, -3, 5, -7, 9, -11...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Is it possible to combine `for loop` and `numpy.tile` to create an alternating incremental array?

Comment: `tile()` repeats the same values, it looks like you want something else. How about `np.arange()`?

Comment: `[(-1)**i * (2*i+1) for i in range(10)] `?

Answer (score 0):

[`numpy.tile(A, reps)` constructs an array by repeating A the number of times given by reps](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html). Since you want to alternate values, I don't think it is possible (or at least, preferable) to use this function to achieve your goal.

How about using only a `for` loop (list comprehension)?

```py
output = [i * (1 if i % 4 == 1 else -1) for i in range(1, 25, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `resize()`:

```
In [38]: np.resize([1,-1], 10) # 10 is the length of result array

Out[38]: array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1])
```

for odd length:

```
In [39]: np.resize([1,-1], 11)

Out[39]: array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1])
```